# Is it possible to reference discrete ranges in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script function that gets me a range from a google spreadsheet.

```
function getGrainWeights() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return range = ss.getRangeByName("Brew_Grains");
}
```

This range is then processed by another function which modifies and upadtes the values in the range.

"Brew_Grains" is a named range in my spreadsheet but I would like to replace it with a discrete range such as "B2,C3,D10" etc.  Is this possible, or is there some workaround?
Cheers

Comment: Related (dup?) question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35510298/405017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following ways to get a range, in addition to the named range used [getRangeByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName%28String%29).

[image: Get a range]

You can find the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer%29).

**UPDATE**

A workaround to what you want to do can be something like:

```
  ...
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var ranges = [];
  var range = ss.getRange('B2:C3');
  ranges.push(range);
  range = ss.getRange('D10');
  ranges.push(range);
  processingFunction(ranges);
  ...
```

You can then pass the array (ranges) to any other function for processing.

Comment: As far as I can work out, getRange(a1Notation) only allows getting a single cell at a time - i.e. I cannot get "B2,C3,D10" as a range? The other methods refer to getting continuous ranges? My current work around is to pass multiple continuous ranges into an array, then do something with that array, then pass the updated array values back to the ranges - a bit clunky!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (as far as I can tell) join two Range objects. However, if you have a custom function that operates on multidimensional arrays, you can convert the ranges into arrays and concatenate those.

For example:

```js
function SUM_RANGE_COLUMN(myRange,colIndex){
  var val,sum=0;
  for (var i=0;i<myRange.length;i++) if (val=myRange[i][colIndex]) sum+=val;
  return sum;
}

function UNION(range1,range2){
  return range1.concat(range2);
}
```

With the above as custom functions, you can write this in your spreadsheet:

```
=SUM_RANGE_COLUMN( UNION(E4:F5,E9:F12), 1 )
```

To convert two real Ranges to arrays, use [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()):

```
function joinRanges( range1, range2 ){
  return range1.getValues().concat( range2.getValues() );
}
```