# Concatenate two ranges in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**tl;dr**: How do I make two ranges appear as one as an argument to a function? For example, I want to look at every cell in column E **except** E5:
`=MY_FUNCTION( somehowjoin( E1:E4, E6:E ) )`

**Background**
I'm writing a project tracker in Google Sheets, like Microsoft Project. I have a [custom function in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35509684/405017) that allows me to calculate the start date for various tasks by looking at the maximum end date of all tasks that it depends upon:

```
=MAX_LOOKUP( G9, A:A, I:I )
```

However, the end date for this task is then calculated based on the start date, and that end date is in the column with all end dates that are examined. As a result, I have a circular dependency.
[image]

So, I'd like to write my formula for each line to skip over the current line, like:

```
=MAX_LOOKUP( G9, A1:A8 + A10:A, I1:I8 + I10:I )
```

---

*FWIW my current workaround is to rewrite the custom function's signature like so:*

```
=MAX_LOOKUP_SKIPROW( G9, ROW(), "A", "I" )
```

*and manually construct the two ranges within that function using:*

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var keys1 = sheet.getRange(keyCol+"1:"+keyCol+(skipRow-1)).getValues();
var vals1 = sheet.getRange(valCol+"1:"+valCol+(skipRow-1)).getValues();

var keys2 = sheet.getRange(keyCol+(skipRow+1)+":"+keyCol).getValues();
var vals2 = sheet.getRange(valCol+(skipRow+1)+":"+valCol).getValues();
```

*This is a functional solution, but makes the function more special purpose. I do not consider this to be an "answer" to this more general question of joining ranges.*

Comment: I'd prefer not to rewrite my custom function to accept multiple arguments, though of course this is a possibility.

Comment: I think a combination of `indirect()` and `row()` could help you construct ranges that exclude the current row.  No?

Comment: @Marc Not as a single argument, as far as I can tell. Am I wrong? Is there a A1 or R1C1 syntax for discontiguous ranges?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18264423/405017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

Create your own arrays and use them as parameters of your custom functions.

## Explanation

In Google Sheets, users could create their own arrays by embracing their elements in brackets.

Instead of

```
=MY_FUNCTION( somehowjoin( E1:E4, E6:E ) )
```

use

```
=MY_FUNCTION({E1:E4;E6:E})
```

## References

[Using arrays in Google Sheets - Google docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was hoping would be possible: a simple, built-in syntax that concatenates discontiguous ranges.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite understanding exactly what you are trying to do, but this might help. You can join ranges like the following. The first two will return the data to a row or a column. I include these just so you can see what is happening. The third I used in a test to make sure the data could be sent to a custom formula. I hope this helps:

```
=split(join(",",A2:A6,A8:A12),",",true)

=transpose(split(join(",",A2:A6,A8:A12),",",true))

=MAX_LOOKUP( G9,  split(join(",",A1:A8,A10:A),",",true),split(join(",",I1:I8,I10:I),",",true) )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a range to a custom function in Google Sheets, the range comes in as an array of arrays. This is a true array, insofar as `Array.isArray()` returns `true`.

Armed with that knowledge, you can create your own custom function:

```js
function UNION(range1,range2){
  return range1.concat(range2);
}
```

And then simply:

```
=MY_FUNCTION( UNION( E1:E4, E6:E ) )
```

...and your original function will have no idea that it is operating on discontiguous ranges that have been merged.

Comment: I hold out hope that a more standard way exists for joining ranges, without resorting to a custom function. I'll not be accepting this answer until it becomes obvious that no better choice is possible.